# Reflect a point about a plane using matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the plane equation $ax + by + cz = d$ and an arbitrary point in 3D space $(i, j, k)$, how do I find a homogenous transformation matrix that is used to reflect this point about the plane?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=(a,b,c)$, and $v=\frac{n}{\|n\|}$ be the plane's normal unit vector, $x=(i,j,k)$ a given vector; then we need to subtract its projection onto $v$ twice to reflect it in the plane: $x-2v(x\cdot v)$. In coordinates: $(I-2vv^T)x$. The transformation matrix $(I-2vv^T)$ is called the [Householder matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).